# MVC 5 specific data of a user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Im new to MVC 5 and dont know much about it. I need to get values specific to current user so i have written this in my controller but it is giving me an error can anyone help?

```
    public ActionResult myIndex()
       {
        var currentUser = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        var plans = (from m in db.BusinessPlans
                     where (m.ApplicationUser == currentUser)
                     select m).ToList();      


        return View(plans);

    }
```

Comment: It would help in future if you specified what the error you are getting is!

Answer (score 0):

Your current user should be saved by any method to session, for example. And next, you will can retrieve it from session like Session["your_key"]. Learn authentication and authorization themes using google to understand how it should work

Answer (score 0):

Code for getting current ApplicationUser

```
string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
```